# Method of Sensitivity and Specificity calculation in repeated cross-validation

Tags: r, r-caret

I would like to understand how the Sensitivity and Specificity is caluculated in `caret::train` when using `summaryFunction=twoClassSummary` and if/how it is possible to change the method.

Example:

```r
library(caret)
library(mlbench)

data(Sonar)

trControl = trainControl("repeatedcv",
                         number = 3,
                         repeats =10,
                         classProbs = TRUE,
                         savePredictions = TRUE,
                         summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

fit <- train(Class ~ ., data=Sonar, 
               method = "glm",
               family=binomial(),
               metric="ROC",
               trControl=trControl)

fit$results
#>   parameter       ROC      Sens      Spec      ROCSD     SensSD     SpecSD
#> 1      none 0.7350712 0.7225225 0.6744949 0.04365911 0.06805355 0.06238508
```

In the `twoClassSummary` function I see how Sens and Spec are calculated (via `caret::sensitivity` and `caret::specificity`).

```r
print(twoClassSummary)
#> function (data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) 
#> {
#>     if (length(lev) > 2) {
#>         stop(paste("Your outcome has", length(lev), "levels. The twoClassSummary() function isn't appropriate."))
#>     }
#>     requireNamespaceQuietStop("pROC")
#>     if (!all(levels(data[, "pred"]) == lev)) {
#>         stop("levels of observed and predicted data do not match")
#>     }
#>     rocObject <- try(pROC::roc(data$obs, data[, lev[1]], direction = ">", 
#>         quiet = TRUE), silent = TRUE)
#>     rocAUC <- if (inherits(rocObject, "try-error")) 
#>         NA
#>     else rocObject$auc
#>     out <- c(rocAUC, sensitivity(data[, "pred"], data[, "obs"], 
#>         lev[1]), specificity(data[, "pred"], data[, "obs"], lev[2]))
#>     names(out) <- c("ROC", "Sens", "Spec")
#>     out
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x000000002f048120>
#> <environment: namespace:caret>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

As far as I know, there are different methods to find optimal thresholds to get Sens and Spec (e.g., youden). According to which method is the Sens and Spec calculated with `TwoClassSummary`?

How could I change `TwoClassSummary` to get Sens and Spec according to youden or "closest topleft" method?

**Update:**

According to [How does caret train determine the probability threshold to maximise Specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45749037/how-does-caret-train-determine-the-probability-threshold-to-maximise-specificity) caret uses a threshold of 0.5 to calculate Sens and Spec, I think this is also true for `metric="ROC"` as in my case.

I am still stuck with changes needed to get Sens/Spec according to Youden using a modified summaryFunction.

Comment: you can look into the function `caret:::sensitivity.default`, `caret:::sensitivity.table`, and ``caret:::sensitivity.matrix`, and adjust them the way you want.

Comment: Thank you. I checked these functions and I see that the sensitivity is calculated using `fit$pred` and `fit$obs`. I do not understand what threshold caret uses to get `fit$pred` (from `fit$M`).

Comment: I think caret uses 0.5 as threshold for Sens and Spec with `twoClassSummary`  as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45749037/how-does-caret-train-determine-the-probability-threshold-to-maximise-specificity)